# Difference between aoColumnDefs and aoColumns

Tags: plugins, jquery-plugins, datatables-1.10

Difference between aoColumnDefs and aoColumns in datatable jquery plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aoColumns requires you to set each column individually (every column is an entry in the array)
aoColumnDefs allows you to set attributes of just some columns, and you can set the same attributes on multiple columns at once (so, you can mark column 2 and 5 to hidden using one entry in the array)

Comment: it might also be important to say aoColumn defines the columns, whereas aoColumnDefs just sets the attributes of columns that are otherwise defined, usually from the data source.